Expo `experiments.typedRoutes` - "Property 'typedRoutes' is not allowed"
app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    [some other config]
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - [WARNING] "Property 'typedRoutes' is not allowed"
    },
    [more config]
  },
}


Expo Docs:

Definition of typedRoutes
More detail on usage of typedRoutes


Why is my IDE (Rider) telling me that the typedRoutes property is "not allowed"??

Additional context:

This warning does not seem to impact the application, but I am quite curious as to why this warning is being shown, is this property obsolete? If it is obsolete, is there a different property to handle this, or is it no longer required?!?

Any information would be greatly appreciated!
